# Navigation bar destroyed when adding a code for divs into CSS

Tags: html, css

Well, I had a perfect menu with this code, just about right with this code in my css file

```
ul.Menu {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #ffffff;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #e9055c;
border-width: 2px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.Menu li{
    border-right: 1px solid #e9055c;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.Menu li a {
    display:block;
    color: #e9055c;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.Menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #f6b0ce;
}

ul.Menu li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

but then I added this to my CSS-code to create a responsive banner via divs at the top of my website:

```
.wrapper {
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden; 
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.banner-img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

and now my menu looks like this- totally crappy with too much space above the menu items...

[image]

I already found out, that it changes, when I'm changing the padding settings on the ul.Menu li a, but I can't get it right with just those...
Can you please help me? :)

Comment: In ul.Menu you use 'margin:' twice. Maybe try to remove the first one, ie: 'margin:10px'

Comment: unfortunately it didn't solve the problem :( still looks the same :o

Comment: add a snippet..

Comment: at the risk to embarass myself: how so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've written the `margin` property twice. Delete the `margin : 0px` style from `ul.Menu`, it is causing the problem.

Comment: unfortunately no :( neither deleting the first nor deleting the second helped

Comment: Write margin Instead of Padding in ul.Menu li a

Comment: omg it worked! the menu looks good now! thanks <3 but when I hover over a menu item now only the text is highlighted and not the whole box anymore... is it possible to fix this, too? :3

Comment: In ul menu li a change display : block; to Display : inline-block;

Comment: that doesn't change anything :o

Comment: remove a from ul menu li a:hover may be it work and mark my answer as best answer ;-D

Comment: oh GOD! It worked :D thanks so much <3 and of course ;)